# Adobe Illustrator scaling image edges

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm having trouble scaling a photo in illustrator.

As you can see when i choose place and the image appears on the canvas the quality is perfect.
[image]

Now when i scale down the quality is bad.  The edges of his head are jagged.

[image]

I don't know if i accidentally changed any setting in illustrator.  I'm working with a client and want to get this done as soon as possible.  The smaller image should be just as smooth, i've scaled down images in the past and the edges haven't looked this bad before.  How do i solve this?

Comment: Why are you using Illustrator to resize a raster image?

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17846/does-photoshop-scale-better-than-illustrator

Answer (score 2):

Ai is a vector based editor, thus scaling down any raster baser images is not a strong side of it.

The best thing I can advise is to scale down the picture in Photoshop or Pixelmator and save it in png format using the settings appropriate to the quality you want to achieve.

Probably the problem is in resolution and format of the image, thus you probably should refer to the raster editor export/save as options.

Using Ai for raster is not advisable - use it if you have no any other choice.

Answer (score 1):

What your looking for is **anti-aliasing**. the best place to find that is photoshop ;). for more info on anti-aliasing in illustrator [go here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15828/illustrator-vector-aliasing)